# looping html tag on the same line using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i feel a bit ridiculous asking this, but i cannot figure out how to get this tag to loop without putting each tag on a new line using asp.net's razor syntax

```
@if (poolitem.SupplierStarRating > 0)
{
     @for (int i = 0; i < poolitem.SupplierStarRating; i++)
     {
          <small class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></small> 
     }
 }
```

what i'm trying to do is avoid that little space that occurs when inline tags are placed on separate lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in one line with no spaces

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){<small class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></small>}
```

It will generate

```
<small class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></small><small class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></small><small class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></small>
```

Comment: awesome, i thought i had tried this, but i still had spaces between the braces and the tag, removed them and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

or you can use @Html.Raw

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Counter; i++)
{
  @Html.Raw("<small class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></small>");
}
```